# Can't find symbol java.io.File?

Tags: java

`import java.io.File`, was in the list before but now netbeans doesn't list class File. And it shows can't find symbol.

Comment: Check if you have JDK included in project CP.

Comment: Is your project set up as a Java project? Is the JRE/JDK on the class path?

Comment: Yes @AK47. It was working. I don't know why it shows an unexpected thing.

Comment: `java.io.File` is a built in -- so if the IDE cannot find the symbol, it means the JDK is not available to the project --- check your class path

Comment: Build class path and then clean the project.

Comment: sorry @AK47, how to check class path? I google it and it shows nothing. Under Libraries folder, there is `JDK 1.8(Default)`.

Comment: Thanks all it works now, I deleted and set a JDK.

Comment: @HenokTesfaye, just a quick comment: JDK 8 is near its end of life. Consider upgrading to Java 11.